# Catch exception from toString method in Java

Tags: java, exception, tostring, throwable

Recently I saw following piece of code on GitHub:

```
private static String safeToString(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return null;
    try {
        return obj.toString();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return "Error occured";
    }
}
```

I've never placed `toString()` method invocations inside the `try-catch` blocks. But now when I think about it, it might make sense. For example someone could overwrite `toString()` method in it's class that might throw a runtime exception, like `NullPointerException`. So we can try to catch `Exception`. But why `Throwable`? Do you think it makes any sense?

Comment: It's normally a bad idea to catch Throwable. If your program (for instance) runs out of memory, you probably don't want it to just carry on oblivious. Especially here, the code ignores any error completely and returns a string as if everything is fine.

Comment: And what do you think about catching Exception from toString()?

Comment: Seems like if `toString()` throws an exception, there's something wrong with your program and you should fix it rather than hiding it.

Comment: But let's say I have a big system with hundreds of classes and just in case I want to ensure that nothing breaks. Would it be OK then?

Comment: You'd be better avoiding the exception than hiding it. But it's your code: write it however you want. At least log the exception though so you will know what happened.

Comment: Quality question for a first timer! +1

Comment: @khelwood Its likely you will want to print out objects for code you didn't write ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey "code you didn't write" might still be written by your coworkers and still be your responsibility when you run into code that's behaving unacceptably. As for code coming from thirdparties the quality of which cannot reasonably said to be your responsibility, well, that may happen... But as a rule of thumb, a thirdparty so good that it's a good idea to use it, tends to not have such annoying defects. It's not a guarantee, but at the very least I wouldn't program as if that was expectable behavior. If a workaround is found to be needed, have it exceptional.

Comment: @kumesana I have rarely seen an Exception in a toString(), and I can't remember ever seeing an Error, but in general, I would prefer a server to keep running even if a log message had a problem being generated.

Comment: @PeterLawrey we all wish that, but literally nothing prevents someone from typing System.exit(0); inside log message generation code. So protecting against such a thing to happen is undoable. Test your systems instead. Figure out whether they do run or not.

Comment: @kumesana You can prevent System.exit(0) but probably shouldn't. You can test your systems for hours or days, but they need to runs for weeks and months, so you can get behaviour in production which doesn't show up in any test you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is almost never a good reason to do this.  The [contract of toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) does not say it’s permissible to throw an exception from that method.  Any code which throws an exception is broken code, and such an exception needs to be exposed and fixed, not suppressed.

In the case where you are converting some “bad” object from a library which is out of your control to a String, it might be appropriate to write `catch (RuntimeExcepton e)`, but such a catch should be accompanied by comments which describe in detail why it is necessary, because under normal circumstances, it is not needed.

Rogue exception-throwing toString methods aside, note that Java already has at least two “safe” ways to convert a possibly null value to a String:

- `Objects.toString(obj, null)`
- `String.valueOf(obj)`

…so I would question whether the safeToString method should exist at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are rare cases where you might want to catch an Error like this.  In general it's a bad idea however, in this case it might make sense as this is generally for logging/debugging purposes and not used directly by the application.

I would prefer something more informative such as

```
private static String safeToString(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return null;
    try {
        return obj.toString();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        return obj.getClass() + ".toString() threw " + t;
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
class Element {
    Object data;
    Element e;

    public String toString() {
        return data + (e == null ? "" : e.toString());
    }
}

Element e = new Element();
e.data = "hi";
e.e = e; // oops

System.out.println("e: " + safeToString(e)); // doesn't kill the thread or JVM.
```

Answer (score 1):

`Throwable` is the parent class of `Exception` and `Error`. 
It is normally a bad idea to try and catch `Error`, as it is designed to not be caught.

Catching `Throwable` is just the overachieved and counterproductive version of catching `Exception`. Nonetheless, if *for some reason* you created another kind of `Throwable` you want to catch along with an `Exception`, that could be a way to do that in a single try/catch block. Not that it would be a clean way to do so, but it would work.

EDIT for the TL;DR : in most cases, catch `Exception` instead of `Throwable`.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to catch any `Throwable` and then continue execution since it includes `Error`, which is meant to be fatal:

From the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Error.html):

> An `Error` is a subclass of `Throwable` that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The [`ThreadDeath`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadDeath.html) error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of `Error` because most applications should not try to catch it.

That is, *some* `Error`s can be recovered (e.g. `LinkageError`), but others not so much.

But catching **`Exception`** might be a valid use-case for example in logging code where you don't want the execution to break simply because a call to `toString()` fails:

```
private static String safeToString(Object obj) {
    try {
        return obj == null ? "null" : obj.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "<exception: " + e + ">";
    }
}
```

Comment: Say you try to print out a linked list which points to itself. Would you prefer your application server to a) print an error, or b) kill the thread leaving the server in an inconsistent state, c) kill the whole server? (See my answer)

Comment: I agree that discarding the Exception isn't helpful and should be in the error.

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger - I only quoted the javadocs from Java 11 :-)

Comment: My mistake, `Thread.stop(Throwable)` has been disabled, but you can still call `Thread.stop()` though you really shouldn't for numerous reasons outlined in the javadoc.